# How to efficiently hash the ip-address

Tags: algorithm, hash

This is an interview question. I thought about some solution like multiway- hashing but could not find some thing elegant. Please suggest some good method.

Question:
You have 10 million IP addresses. (IPv4 4 byte addresses). Create a hash function for these IP addresses.

Hint: Using the IP's themselves as a key is a bad idea because there will be a lot of wasted space

Comment: Why does an optimal hash key (one that is always unique) waste space? If at all, that would be a problem of your specific implementation of the hash table.

Comment: IPv4 address itself is already a 32-bit integer. So theoretically anything that applies to integer should work here. Unless there's assumption on the distribution of the IPs. For instance, are they from different subnets or is distinguishing between subnets crucial?

Comment: what is the desired key size?

Comment: Your hint does not make a lot of sense. In Java, Scala and Haskell, the key refers to the actual data from which the hash code is produced - in this case the IP address itself. Furthermore, even if "key" refers to "hash code", it still does not make sense to me, because in Java and Scala, "hash code" refers to the raw hash code prior to normalising it to the current size of the hash table.

Comment: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html

Comment: Specify size of table to use for hashing .

Comment: As this is a interview question. I do not have to much detail about it. Here is what I think.-- As address would be allotted in the blocks and all the ip-address would not be used. So in case using general hashing might not be the best idea. 2. @perreal No desired key size mentioned.

Comment: @Vikram - no such limit. But definitely less space and fast access is better.

Comment: @Abhishek You can see my answer there tell me if you are not convinced.

Comment: V4 IP addresses are 4 bytes so realistically there isn't any hashing algorithm that would protect them for long, A salt might help but only if you can guarantee that the salt doesn't get disclosed.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting, that such an interesting question did not have any interesting answer (sorry for tautology).

If you see it as a theoretical matter, then this link is what you need (there is even a `superfast` hash function written for you and ready to go):

http://www.kfki.hu/~kadlec/sw/netfilter/ct3/

Practical matter may be different. If your hash table is of reasonable size, you will have to handle collisions anyway (with linked lists). So ask yourself what use case will take place in the end? If your code will run within some secluded ecosystem, and the IP address is `a-b-c-d`, `c` and `d` are the most volatile numbers and `d` won't be null (assuming you don't handle networks), so a hash table of 64K buckets, and `cd` as a hash may well be satisfactory?

Another use case - TCP connection tracking where a client use ephemeral port that is assigned by kernel randomly (isn't it ideal for hashing?). The problem is the limited range: something like 32768-61000 which renders least significant byte more random than most significant byte. So you can XOR the most significant byte with the most volatile byte in IP address that can be zerro (`c`) and use it as a hash in your 64K table.

Comment: I don't think that's a tautology, more like a conduplicatio

Answer (score 0):

Because your input is random & size of table is smaller the address space any hash function that you design will have its own pathological data set which will make your hash function look bad. I think the interviewer wants to know your knowledge about existing hash function that are used as standards.

Following are few such hash functions :

1. MD5
2. SHA-1,SHA-2

Why these functions work better than other hash functions because their pathelogical data sets are difficult to find without using brute force algorithms. So if you have something as good as these than donot tell your interviewer (you can get a patent on it and get job in google).

For Hashing ip addresses use MD5 or SHA on it and truncate to the size of table and you are done.

**Note:**- Size of table must be prime to prevent bad hashing.

Comment: Cost can be very important for hashing. MD5 and SHA are costly hashes for something as small as an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same question before.

To solve this, you should divide your data.
We know ip address is consequent.

1. table1 from 0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.127   (they are all in New York town1)
2. table2 from 0.0.0.128 to 0.0.0.255 (they are all in New York town2)
3. ....

Then, create a map like this.

1. 0.0.0.0~0.0.0.127   -> address1
2. 0.0.0.127~0.0.0.255 -> address2
3. ......

Then, to get the address for the IP, just get value from map;

Note: all the data is in database, I don't think it cost lots of space, to get the address in 1s, you should cost several space to optimize the speed